# How can I add a button inside a clickable row in a table

Tags: reactjs, button, html-table, onclick, event-handling

I am not sure if this is even possible but I have a table that has an onClick event on each row that directs the user to another page. I need to add a button inside each row to handle a separate event. But everytime I click the button the action to redirect to a new page is fired. Is it possible to have a click event inside another?

example:

```
items.map((item) => {
  return(
    <tr onClick={onClick(item.value)}>
      <td>{item.Name}</td>
      <td>
         {visitCreated}
          <span>
            <button 
              type="button" 
              onClick={handlePreview(item.referenceID)}>
                  Preview
            </button>
          </span>
       </td>
      <td>{item.Encounters}</td>
    </tr>
})
```

Anytime I click the  both events are triggered. How can I isolate them?

Comment: Obviously - thats what I would expect.  Add another button.  And remove the event from the row

Answer (score 2):

You can add an id on the button, and check if the target has this id to prevent one or the other event. Something like

```
function onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.id !== 'button_id') {
      // do something
    }
    event.stopPropagation()
}

function handlePreview(event) {
     if (event.target.id === 'button_id') {
      // do something else
    }
    event.stopPropagation()
}

...

 items.map((item) => {
      return(
        <tr onClick={onClick(item.value)}>
          <td>{item.Name}</td>
          <td>
             {visitCreated}
              <span>
                <button 
                  type="button" 
                  id="button_id"
                  onClick={handlePreview(item.referenceID)}>
                      Preview
                </button>
              </span>
           </td>
          <td>{item.Encounters}</td>
        </tr>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to wrap the onClick handlers in an arrow function:

```
onClick={()=>onClick(item.value)}

onClick={()=>handlePreview(item.referenceID)}
```

```
items.map((item) => {
  return(
    <tr onClick={()=>onClick(item.value)}>
      <td>{item.Name}</td>
      <td>
         {visitCreated}
          <span>
            <button 
              type="button" 
              onClick={()=>handlePreview(item.referenceID)}>
                  Preview
            </button>
          </span>
       </td>
      <td>{item.Encounters}</td>
    </tr>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log("Clicked the button");
    e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});

const rowClick = (event) => {
    console.log("Clicked the row");
};
```

```css
tr {
  display: flex;
}

td {
  
  border: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr onclick={rowClick()}>
        <td>{item.Name}</td>
        <td>
           {visitCreated}
            <span>
              <button
                class="previewButton" 
                type="button" >
                    Preview
              </button>
            </span>
         </td>
        <td>{item.Encounters}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnv7opa9/)